# Expected Value functions of two randon variables

Tags: random-variables

$X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables.
$f$, $g$ and $h$ are 3 functions.

Can the below expected value be calculated?

$$E\left[ f(X)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor g(X) \rfloor }h(Y) \right]$$

$\lfloor g(X) \rfloor$ is capped by $n$. 
So I was thinking I could calculate the $n$ cases separately, and then average the results (weighted by their probability).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Z = f(X) \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor g(X) \rfloor} h(Y)$.  Then
$E[Z|X] = f(X) (1+\lfloor g(X) \rfloor) E[h(Y)]$, so 
$$E[Z] = E \left[ f(X) (1+\lfloor g(X) \rfloor) \right] E[h(Y)]$$

Comment: That looks like formally confirming what I thought, so thank you very much Robert.